# Simple Machines Forums merge login with website

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, smf-forum

So i want my users to only register and login once. I already have the registration part working and they can manually login to the forum but i want to merge my login for website and forum.

My website users will have same userid as forum users and same password encryption sha1( lowercase(username) + password ).

How can i use $_COOKIE[]... to create a SMF login cookie so that when they click on Forum they are redirected to the forum and already logged in.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Website will have about 10 users so a very very crude and simple option will do.

> I have tried following this tutorial
>   http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html to have
>   my Codeigniter application fill that login form and post it but no
>   succsses.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12486750/568884) here.

Comment: Have you checked the SMF API? From memory, there's code in there that will do it for you.